# How can I visualise an image in h5 format data?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, hdf5, h5py

```
import h5py
f = h5py.File('the_file.h5', 'r')
one_data = f['key']
print(one_data.shape)
print(one_data.dtype)
print(one_data)
```

I use the code above to print the info.
The print result is:

```
(320, 320, 3)
uint8
<HDF5 dataset "1458552843.750": shape (320, 320, 3), type "|u1">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import h5py
f = h5py.File('the_file.h5', 'r')
dset = f['key']
data = np.array(dset[:,:,:])
file = 'test.jpg'
cv2.imwrite(file, data)
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution provided by *jet* works just fine, but has the drawback of needing to include OpenCV (cv2). In case you are not using OpenCV for anything else, it is a bit overkill to install/include it just for saving the file. Alternatively you can use `imageio.imwrite` ([doc](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userapi.html#imageio.imwrite)) which has lighter footprint, e.g.:

```
import imageio
import numpy as np
import h5py

f = h5py.File('the_file.h5', 'r')
dset = f['key']
data = np.array(dset[:,:,:])
file = 'test.png' # or .jpg
imageio.imwrite(file, data)
```

Installing imageio is as simple as `pip install imageio`.

Also, `matplotlib.image.imsave` ([doc](https://matplotlib.org/api/image_api.html#matplotlib.image.imsave)) provides similar image saving functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It can be even simpler:

```sh
pip install Pillow h5py
```

Then

```py
import h5py
from PIL import Image

f = h5py.File('the_file.h5', 'r')
dset = f['key'][:]
img = Image.fromarray(dset.astype("uint8"), "RGB")
img.save("test.png")
```